# Simple Wordpress Configuration Not Redirecting to Root

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm using pretty simple nginx boilerplate here, but it appears my server isn't listening when I attempt to access my domain's root. Here's my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.dev.company.com ;
        root /var/www/wordpress/ ;

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, I should be getting the index.php I have set up in /var/www/wordpress when I make a request to blog.dev.company.com. Instead, the site just hangs. The domain name is found, but nginx does not process the request. The nginx access log is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `location` such as this to handle PHP scripts?

```
# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include         fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;   
}
```